# Setting opacity to canvas fabricjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fabricjs, draw

After I draw polygon i would like to change opacity of canvas out of polygon i just drawn. I think it might have something to do with clipping but im not sure. Polygon and lines inside should have 100% opacity but everything else (background and lines outside polygon should have 50% opacity)

```
prototypefabric.polygon = {
    drawPolygon: function () {
        canvas.on('mouse:down', function (options) {
            if (options.target && options.target.id == pointArray[0].id) {
                prototypefabric.polygon.generatePolygon(pointArray);
            }
            if (polygonMode) {
                prototypefabric.polygon.addPoint(options);
            }
        });
        canvas.on('mouse:up', function (options) {

        });
        canvas.on('mouse:move', function (options) {
            if (activeLine && activeLine.class == "line") {
                var pointer = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
                activeLine.set({x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y});

                var points = activeShape.get("points");
                points[pointArray.length] = {
                    x: pointer.x,
                    y: pointer.y
                };
                activeShape.set({
                    points: points
                });
                canvas.renderAll();
            }
            canvas.renderAll();
        });
        polygonMode = true;
        pointArray = new Array();
        lineArray = new Array();
        activeLine;
    },
    addPoint: function (options) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        var id = new Date().getTime() + random;
        var circle = new fabric.Circle({
            radius: 5,
            fill: '#ffffff',
            stroke: '#333333',
            strokeWidth: 0.5,
            left: (options.e.layerX / canvas.getZoom()),
            top: (options.e.layerY / canvas.getZoom()),
            selectable: false,
            hasBorders: false,
            hasControls: false,
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center',
            id: id
        });
        if (pointArray.length == 0) {
            circle.set({
                fill: '#BB2026'
            })
        }
        var points = [(options.e.layerX / canvas.getZoom()), (options.e.layerY / canvas.getZoom()), (options.e.layerX / canvas.getZoom()), (options.e.layerY / canvas.getZoom())];
        line = new fabric.Line(points, {
            strokeWidth: 2,
            fill: '#999999',
            stroke: 'green',
            class: 'line',
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center',
            selectable: false,
            hasBorders: false,
            hasControls: false,
            evented: false
        });
        if (activeShape) {
            var pos = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
            var points = activeShape.get("points");
            points.push({
                x: pos.x,
                y: pos.y
            });
            var polygon = new fabric.Polygon(points, {
                stroke: '#333333',
                strokeWidth: 1,
                fill: '#cccccc',
                opacity: 0.3,
                selectable: false,
                hasBorders: false,
                hasControls: false,
                evented: false,
            });
            canvas.remove(activeShape);
            canvas.add(polygon);
            activeShape = polygon;
            canvas.renderAll();
            console.log(points);
        } else {
            var polyPoint = [{x: (options.e.layerX / canvas.getZoom()), y: (options.e.layerY / canvas.getZoom())}];
            var polygon = new fabric.Polygon(polyPoint, {
                stroke: '#333333',
                strokeWidth: 1,
                fill: '#cccccc',
                opacity: 0.3,
                selectable: false,
                hasBorders: false,
                hasControls: false,
                evented: false,
            });
            activeShape = polygon;
            canvas.add(polygon);
        }
        activeLine = line;

        pointArray.push(circle);
        lineArray.push(line);

        canvas.add(line);
        canvas.add(circle);
        canvas.selection = false;
    },
    generatePolygon: function (pointArray) {
        var points = new Array();
        $.each(pointArray, function (index, point) {
            points.push({
                x: point.left,
                y: point.top,
            });
            canvas.remove(point);
        });
        $.each(lineArray, function (index, line) {
            canvas.remove(line);
        });
        canvas.remove(activeShape).remove(activeLine);
        var polygon = new fabric.Polygon(points, {
            stroke: '#333333',
            strokeWidth: 0.5,
            fill: 'rgb(255, 255, 255, 0)',
            hasBorders: false,
            hasControls: false,
            id: 'plotOutline'
        });
        canvas.add(polygon);

        var overlayRect = new fabric.Rect({
            width: canvas.get("width"),
            height: canvas.get("height"),
            selectable: false,
            fill: "rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5)"
        });

        var clippingPolygon = new fabric.Polygon(polygon.points, {
            left: -(overlayRect.get("width") / 2) - polygon.get("left") * -1,
            top: -(overlayRect.get("height") / 2) - polygon.get("top") * -1
        });

        var clipGroup = new fabric.Group([clippingPolygon], {
            inverted: true
        });

        overlayRect.clipPath = clipGroup;
        canvas.add(overlayRect);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(polygon.points) + 'points');

        if (polygon.id == 'plotOutline') {
            $('#saveStepOne').prop('disabled', false);
        }

        activeLine = null;
        activeShape = null;
        polygonMode = false;
        canvas.selection = true;
    }
};
```

drawing polygon

Comment: What is the version of FabricJS you are using? Is it 1.7? I will try to find a solution. As for now, I can think of applying a transparent layer and then using a clipPath on that opacity layer.

Comment: I'm using 3.6.3 version. Will clip path work with freshly drawn polygon? Polygon itself has ID so it could i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can obtain it the opacity of everything outside a specific polygon (that could be a previously dynamically created). I just don't know how to get the drawing line outside to also have the opacity applied:

You can also check this demo SandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-60810389-fabric-js-362-vm92q

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
  isDrawingMode: true
});

fabric.Image.fromURL("https://picsum.photos/500/350", function(img) {
  // add background image
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    scaleX: canvas.width / img.width,
    scaleY: canvas.height / img.height
  });
});

var originalPolygon = new fabric.Polygon(
  [{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 250, y: 0 }, { x: 220, y: 140 }, { x: 0, y: 140 }],
  {
    left: 10,
    top: 10,
    fill: "white",
    stroke: "red",
    strokeWidth: 2,
    selectable: false
  }
);

// An Overlay that covers the whole canvas
var overlayRect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: canvas.get("width"),
  height: canvas.get("height"),
  selectable: false,
  fill: "rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8)"
});

// The clipPath object uses top,left,scale.... to position itself starting from the center of the object that is clipping
// For more details check https://github.com/fabricjs/api-discussion/issues/1
var clippingPolygon = new fabric.Polygon(originalPolygon.points, {
  left: -(overlayRect.get("width") / 2) - originalPolygon.get("left") * -1,
  top: -(overlayRect.get("height") / 2) - originalPolygon.get("top") * -1
});

var clipGroup = new fabric.Group([clippingPolygon], {
  inverted: true
});

overlayRect.clipPath = clipGroup;

// Comment adding of the orgiinalPolygon to see better the clipping effect
canvas.add(originalPolygon);
canvas.add(overlayRect);

canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
canvas {
  border: 2px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.2/fabric.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="350"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine and it's what I was looking for, but when Im trying to set it on dynamicly added polygon it doesn't work sadly. Could you please have a look on it? I got console log with polygon points but somehow it's now working. (I've edited question code with your code added)